# Is it possible to keep the ScrollBar position after the pane is resized in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

So lets say we have a ScrollPane with a vertical ScrollBar.

Inside the ScrollPane we have a FlowPane that expands vertically.

Inside the FlowPane we have a large number of small elements.

Now lets say I have my stage window at 500x500 size and the ScrollBar on the scrollpane is positioned somewhere around 0.5.

If I expand the stage window and make it full screen, the FlowPane size will also be expanded and it will have more width available to it and therefore it's height will be decreased as more elements inside of it will be able to fit in a row, and therefore the flowpane will have less rows.

This will cause the scrollbar to jump to position somewhere around 0.9(very roughly)

I do not like this behavior, I need the scroll bar to stay at 0.5 position.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: You want the scroll position stay at 0.5 when items are added?

Comment: whenever the height of the content of the scrollpane changes, so yes when Items are added too.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by attaching a ListChangeListener to FlowPane's children. Something like this:

```
        FlowPane flowPane=new FlowPane();
        ScrollPane scrollPane=new ScrollPane(flowPane);

        flowPane.getChildren().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Node>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Change<? extends Node> c)
            {
                scrollPane.setHvalue(0.5); //sets the horizontal scroll
                scrollPane.setVvalue(0.5); //sets the vertical scroll
            }
        });
```